# Nested if condition not working properly

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow

I am facing a small issue with the nested if condition in 2010 SharePoint workflow platform.

I have nested if-else statement in a 2010 workflow but only the first condition executes and not the other conditions.
Status is a lookup column.

```
If(Status==Value)
    send email
else if(status==value2)
    send email
else if(status==value3)
    send email
```

Please do help me out in this.

Thanks.

Comment: firstly you could log the used values in the if statement to history so that you can see which values are compared. Secondly if you use a lookup column it could be a question of the return type you use like in https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/169887/if-lookup-equals-string-doesnt-always-work-sometimes-i-have-to-use-1str

Comment: i kind of know the problem of lookup value returning with 1;#value and i was comparing it the same way but only my first condition is executed & never the other values. i would try it with workflow variable and get back to you if it is working or not.